# Read data from arduino and add timestamp

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I want to send data from arduino to computer by using serial. Then i want to record the time based on the current timestamp and i save it in the txt file. What should I do? Your suggestions are very useful to me.

this my code on arduino:

```
#include <DHT.h>

#define DHTPIN 2   
#define DHTTYPE DHT11  

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    dht.begin();
}
void loop(){
    float hum = dht.readHumidity();
    float temp= dht.readTemperature();

    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(hum);
    Serial.print(" %, Temp: ");
    Serial.print(temp);
    Serial.println(" Celsius");
    delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving the data over the serial port on the computer? Where's your Python code that reads it in?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this python script as your receiver code.
Change 'port' to your Arduino port.

To find your Arduino port, before you plug it in, in the shell terminal use

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

Use it again after you have plugged your Arduino in and compare the lists to find the new connection. (For me, it ended up being ACM0)

Do not forget to download serial library if it is missing: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

```
import serial
import time
import datetime

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    timestamp = str(time.time())
    #timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    with open('output.txt', 'a') as pyfile:
        pyfile.write(line + ' ' + timestamp +'\n')

ser.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are on Windows, you can Try this Free console application:
https://hiterminallogger.sourceforge.io/
Just download and run the exe in a bash console emulator

```
$./HiTerminalLogger.exe COM<portnumber> 9600
```

you will get it Timestamped log as well as html report.
you can as well as highlight the Text to make it more conspicuous.

[image]

Comment: I tried "HiTerminalLogger.exe" and it works in Git bash. It does not work in Windows cmd shell.

Answer (score 0):

## Use ts!

On any Unix and in Windows Subsystem for Linux (aka. WSL) you can install `moreutils` which includes the `ts` tool. `ts` adds timestamps to text data that is fed to its standard input.

**Installation** on, e.g., Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

**Usage**

Assuming that your serial port is, e.g., `ttyS70`, you can run this command line to

- read serial data from this port (using `cat`),
- add a timestamp (using `ts`), and
- print out the resulting line and at the same time save it to a file (using `tee`):

```
$ cat /dev/ttyS70 | ts | tee logfile
```

For my kind of serial data, the result looks like this:

```
Feb 14 18:37:03 13438 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
Feb 14 18:37:03 13440 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
Feb 14 18:37:04 13441 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
Feb 14 18:37:04 13442 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
Feb 14 18:37:04 13444 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
```

In this example, the serial port receives more than one line per second. Don't fret, `ts` allows you to control how the timestamp is formatted. For example `%.s` will give you seconds since 1970 in sub-second resolution:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyS70 | ts %.s | tee logfile
```

results in

```
1676396776.277146 18963 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.405363 18964 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.532999 18966 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.660920 18967 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.789261 18968 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.917136 18969 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
```

If you don't need absolute time data, use the switch `-s`. This will give you the time elapsed since start of the program:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyS70 | ts -s %.s | tee logfile
```

results in

```
0.072230 6459 42     0     0.0  20567 -100.00    0.00 1
0.199964 6459 42     0     0.0  20567 -100.00    0.00 1
0.311792 6460 42     0     0.0  20568 -100.00    0.00 1
0.439221 6460 42     0     0.0  20566 -100.00    0.00 1
0.567191 6460 42     0     0.0  20566 -100.00    0.00 1
0.694773 6460 42     0     0.0  20566 -100.00    0.00 1
0.822279 6461 42     0     0.0  20567 -100.00    0.00 1
0.950085 6461 42     0     0.0  20566 -100.00    0.00 1
1.061797 6461 42     0     0.0  20567 -100.00    0.00 1
1.189510 6461 42     0     0.0  20568 -100.00    0.00 1
```